# Is it possible to detect Gender using Google.Cloud.Vision

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform

I found some code examples of detecting face:

```
 var image = Image.FromFile(filePath);
        var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
        var response = client.DetectFaces(image);
        int count = 1;
        foreach (var faceAnnotation in response)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Face {0}:", count++);
            Console.WriteLine("  Joy: {0}", faceAnnotation.JoyLikelihood);

            Console.WriteLine("  Anger: {0}", faceAnnotation.AngerLikelihood);
            Console.WriteLine("  Sorrow: {0}", faceAnnotation.SorrowLikelihood);
            Console.WriteLine("  Surprise: {0}", faceAnnotation.SurpriseLikelihood);
        }
```

But I couldn't find 'IsMale' or 'Gender' property in faceAnnotation. How can I detect Gender using Google.Cloud.Vision?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, gender isn't supported by Cloud Vision.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Hmmm, got it! Can you suggest any API to detect gender in .Net?

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't looked at any other vision APIs. (I maintain the Google Cloud client libraries, but I haven't looked at many others.)

Comment: It's not supported at the moment by google vision api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think AWS Rekognition could provide gender:

Q: What face attributes can I get from Amazon Rekognition?

Amazon Rekognition returns the following facial attributes for each face detected, along with a bounding box and confidence score for each attribute:

1. Gender
2. Smile
   ...

see: https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/faqs/

Comment: Is it free API?

Comment: Probably not, most of the machine learning APIs are paid for. Some might offer some free tier but things like this keep changing so best to look at the billing section to get up-to-date information.